# What's wrong with my regex to extract time from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex to extract time out of a string to build an application.

Here's what I've got so far. Not sure what am I doing wrong here.

https://regex101.com/r/fC0lI5/1

I can get some the string but not all of the different variations.

```
([01]?[0-9]*:?[0-9]*[AP]M?)-([01]?[0-9]*:?[0-9]*[AP]M?)


8-8:30AM MON TUES THURS FRI
8-10:30AM MON TUES THURS FRI
8:30AM-10:30AM MON TUES THURS FRI
10:30AM-11:30AM MON TUES THURS FRI
10:30AM-11:30AM MON TUES THURS FRI
8AM-8:30AM
10-11PM
```

What I want is two captured groups. So I know that the first group is `FROM` time and the later one is `TO` time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)-([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)
           ^^               ^^            ^^                 ^^
```

Just make `AM` component optional.See demo.Also make first part `+` or else it will match empty strings.

https://regex101.com/r/fC0lI5/2

Comment: yours will match `10M-12M`, which doesn't make sense

Comment: This matches `10:30A-10:31M`

Comment: `[AP]?M?` should be instead `(?:[AP]M)?`

Comment: This matches a lot more than needed: 3782328328-23 for example

Answer (score 5):

The AM/PM in either capture group is not optional

```
([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)-([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)
```

I think mine is more valid than the others because the others will allow (they've since fixed theirs)

```
8M-9M, which is not valid.
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by other answers, the A and P are not optional. Furthermore, your regex will match other strings (like ":A-:A" or "98387899A-A").

This works and will be stricter that yours:

```
((?:[01]?[0-9]:)?[0-9]{1,2}(?:AM|PM)?)-((?:[01]?[0-9]:)?[0-9]{1,2}(?:AM|PM)?)
```

See [the Python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for a complete description of the regex syntax.

Comment: We actually cannot use regex to validate time ...it would be tough....like this will match 0-0.nonetheless plus one